# How to ignore unpacked parts of a tuple as argument of a lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, tuples, iterable-unpacking, argument-unpacking

In Python, by convention, the underscore (`_`) is often used to throw away parts of an unpacked tuple, like so

```
>>> tup = (1,2,3)
>>> meaningfulVariableName,_,_ = tup
>>> meaningfulVariableName
1
```

I'm trying to do the same for a tuple argument of a lambda. It seems unfair that it can only be done with 2-tuples...

```
>>> map(lambda (meaningfulVariableName,_): meaningfulVariableName*2, [(1,10), (2,20), (3,30)]) # This is fine
[2, 4, 6]

>>> map(lambda (meaningfulVariableName,_,_): meaningfulVariableName*2, [(1,10,100), (2,20,200), (3,30,300)]) # But I need this!
SyntaxError: duplicate argument '_' in function definition (<pyshell#24>, line 1)
```

Any ideas why, and what the best way to achieve this is?

Comment: `lambda x, *_: x*2`

Comment: Or `lambda t: t[0] * 2` depending on the call

Comment: Or `lambda (x, dummy1, dummy2): x * 2`

Comment: Or just write a function.

Comment: You can't put an unpacking in a function's argument list at all in Python 3 - the `lambda (x, y): whatever` and `def f((x, y)): whatever` syntax is completely gone.

Comment: good to mention is that  `_` is variable just in interactive shell and it stores last operation result, so if You write for example `2+2` in interactive shell the result is stored in this variable.

Comment: @timgeb your suggestion is not working for me:
`map(lambda meaningfulVariableName,*_: meaningfulVariableName*2, [(1,10,100), (2,20,200), (3,30,300)])`

Comment: @MichaelButscher `t[0]` is not as readable as `meaningfulVariableName` (see updated question), and `lambda (x, dummy1, dummy2)` is exactly what I am trying to avoid with `_`

Answer (score 5):

As it is in the comments, just use stared arguments
to throw an remaining arguments in "_":

```
lambda x, *_: x*2
```

If you were using these in a `map` statement, as Python does not map each item in a tuple to a different parameter, you could use `itertools.starmap`, that does that:

```
from itertools import starmap
result = map(lambda x, *_: x, [(0,1,2),])
```

But there is no equivalent to that on the key parameter to `sort` or `sorted`.

If you won't be using arguments in the middle of the tuple,
just number those:

```
lambda x, _1, _2, _3, w: x*2 + w
```

If you get a complaint from some linter tool about the parameters not being used: the purpose of the linter is to suggest mor readable code. My personal preference is not to let that to be in the way of practicity, and if this happens, I just turn off the linter for that line of code, without a second thought.

Otherwise, you will really have to do the "beautiful" thing - just use good sense if it is to please you and your team, or solely to please the linter. In this case, it is to write a full fledged function, and pretend
to consume the unused arguments.

```
def my_otherwise_lambda(x, unused_1, unused_2, w):
     """My make linter-happy docstring here"""
     unused_1, unused_2  # Use the unused variables
     return 2 * x + w
```

Short of having a problem with the linter, is the purpose is to have the lambda parameter readable, then habing a full-fledged function is the recomended anyway. `lambda` was really close of being stripped of the language in v. 3.0, in order to commit to readability.

And last, but not least, if the semantics of the value in your tuples is *that* meaningful, maybe you should consider using a class to hold the values in there. In that way you could just pass the instances of that class to the lambda funcion and check the values bytheir respective names.

Namedtuple is one that would work well:
from collections import namedtuple

```
vector = namedtuple("vector", "x y z")

mydata = [(1,10,100), (2,20,200), (3,30,300)]
mydata = [vector(*v) for v in mydata]

sorted_data = sorted(mydata, lambda v: v.x * 2)
```

Comment: Pylint has a configurable regex for the names of unused variables.  `unused.*` should be included in the default configuration.  (Of course there are more Python linters, but pylint is a very common one.)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not do what I expect: `map(lambda meaningfulVariableName,*_: meaningfulVariableName*2, [(1,10,100), (2,20,200), (3,30,300)])`

Comment: Yes, `sort` won't "star"  the call to lambda for you - you really will have to either create an explicit function, or use @ariOpenheimer's suggestion, and just pick the tuple index inside the lambda.

Comment: @Julian The "destructuring" syntax you used for the lambdas in your question was removed from Python because it was considered too obscure and is rarely used.  It should be considered deprecated and not used in new code; all code will have to be migrated to Python 3 soon anyway.  So for a key function in `sorted()`, just write a proper function and umpack the tuple in the first line of that function.  Or alternatively, use `namedtuple`s, so you can use `sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x.last_name, x.first_name))`, or whatever the names of your fields are.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments. It sounds like the answer is, "There is no way in Python (any version) to do what you want with lambdas". I am happy to accept that answer if somebody writes it. @Sven Marnach, a bit off-topic, but out of interest why do you say that all code will have to be migrated to Python 3 soon? My client is not showing any intention to move from 2.6...

Comment: Your client will then be stuck with the system running in an unmaintained version of the language, that will pile up security bugs as they are discovered, and slowly starts failing interaction with the rest of the operational system.

Comment: Well, OK not everybody migrated from Windows XP (or earlier), have they? :-)

Comment: @Julian I'll just reply with two links: https://snarky.ca/stop-using-python-2-6/ and https://pythonclock.org/.  Note that the first blog post is too years old.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable in Python so you won't be able to "throw away" (modify) the extraneous values.

Additionally, since you don't care about what those values are, there is absolutely no need to assign them to variables.

What I would do, is to simply index the tuple at the index you are interested in, like so:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0] * 2, [(1,10,100), (2,20,200), (3,30,300)]))
[2, 4, 6]
```

No need for `*args` or dummy variables.

Comment: I do not want to mutate the tuple.
As for the `x[0]` suggestion, it is not as readable as `meaningfulVariableName` (see updated question).

Comment: this is not what is being asked;

Comment: @Julian, Actually, since you want to operate on a single element in a tuple, that is not starred (so you will have the whole tuple as argument to your lambda), this is the only way to go.

Comment: @Julian there's no mention of how to do this in PEP 8, so it falls to a matter of personal preference. I personally find efficient, concise code to be more readable, but not everyone shares that opinion.

Comment: You can use a meaningful index instead. tup = (1, 2, 3) -> NAME_IDX = 0 -> tup(NAME_IDX) means get the name.

Answer (score 1):

You are often better off to use list comprehensions rather than `lambda`s:

```
some_list = [(1, 10, 100), (2, 20, 200), (3, 30, 300)]
processed_list = [2 * x for x, dummy1, dummy2 in some_list]
```

If you really insist, you could use `_` instead of `dummy1` and `dummy2` here.  However, I recommend against this, since I've frequently seen this causing confusion. People often think `_` is some kind of special syntax (which it is e.g. in Haskell and Rust), while it is just some unusual variable name without any special properties.  This confusion is completely avoidable by using names like `dummy1`.  Moreover, `_` clashes with the common gettext alias, and it also *does* have a special meaning in the interactive interpreter, so overall I prefer using `dummy` to avoid all the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, but my real application (`sorted(mess, key=lambda...)`) cannot be expressed by a list comprehension.

Comment: @Julian The application given in your question is `map(lambda, ...)`, which is what I wrote this answer for.  For `sorted()`, you can use `operator.itemgetter()` instead of a lambda for simple cases.